# Как на питоне из переменной сделать список?

Tags: python, list

Например, у меня есть переменная "text" и у нее есть какое-то значение, как из нее сделать список, так что-бы каждый символ переменной "text" был отдельный элементом списка?

Comment: `text = list(text)`

Answer (score 2):

```py
text = '1234'
text = list(text)
print(text)
# ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = [text[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(text))]
```

Если за символ считать всё, включая пробелы, переносы строк и тд.

Comment: `text = [text[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(text))]` а зачем такие трудности? во-первых, срезы тут не нужны, просто `text[i]`, во-вторых, индексы тут нафиг не нужны, просто: `text = [c for c in text]`